# C++ WinHttp request is sent as TCP?

Tags: c++, http, tcp, httprequest, wireshark

Here is my code: http://pastebin.com/znrwaT0n
When you press enter it should send a usual HTTP GET request to www.google.com.
As you can see it also successfully receives the HTML-code.
But for some reason Wireshark and other network monitors don't detect that it was sent as HTTP request, they just mark it as TCP (while other HTTP requets get marked as "HTTP") and the data doesn't seem to be readable to humans.

Could you explain me why this happens, what the side-effects are and how I could avoid it?

Comment: Maybe you can post a wireshark capture ? comparing your request and a browser one

Comment: Are you hitting HTTPS by chance?  Wireshark's `http` filter only works for port 80 by default.

Comment: it actually seems to be an https problem. It doesn't matter what server send the request to, it's everytime an https. How can I disable that? Here is the capture: 11 5.184325000 192.168.2.105 198.252.206.16 TCP 66 49965 > https [SYN] Seq=0 Win=8192 Len=0 MSS=1460 WS=256 SACK_PERM=1

Comment: I solved it. I had to set the port to INTERNET_DEFAULT_HTTP_PORT and the flag in WinHttpOpenRequest() to NULL.

Comment: Though I'm wondering why Fiddler doesn't catch the request. oO 
This is what it looks like in Wireshark: 16 3.432776000 192.168.2.105 198.252.206.16 HTTP 207 GET / HTTP/1.1

Answer (score 1):

May be the port is not '80'. If so, set the Wireshark to decode the Transport layer of capture as HTTP (both on the receiving and sending side)